# Working example of rtpvrawpay in GStreamer

Tags: gstreamer

Can someone paste a working pair of gst-launch pipelines that use `rtpvrawpay` and `rtpvrawdepay`?

Here's my first stab at it:

`gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,width=128,height=128,format=BGR ! rtpvrawpay ! application/x-rtp,payload=96 ! udpsink host=... port=...`

`gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=9999 ! application/x-rtp,media=video,payload=96,clock-rate=90000,encoding-name=RAW,sampling=BGR,depth=16 !  rtpvrawdepay ! video/x-raw,width=128,height=128,format=BGR,framerate=30/1 ! videoconvert ! ximagesink`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pay:    `gst-launch-1.0 -v videotestsrc ! rtpvrawpay ! udpsink host="127.0.0.1" port="5000"`

Depay: `gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port="5000" caps = "application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)RAW, sampling=(string)YCbCr-4:2:0, depth=(string)8, width=(string)320, height=(string)240, colorimetry=(string)BT601-5, payload=(int)96, ssrc=(uint)1103043224, timestamp-offset=(uint)1948293153, seqnum-offset=(uint)27904" ! rtpvrawdepay ! videoconvert ! queue ! xvimagesink sync=false`

Check the caps on your pipeline again.

Comment: Yes and for some reason if I did a caps filter with this syntax: `udpsrc ! application/x-rtp,...` it didn't work.  Copying the exact caps from the sending pipeline and putting it into the `caps` property of `udpsrc` works.